# Forcing sidebar scroll using flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to build two column layout using flexbox css. Page should consist of header, sidebar, content area and footer.

One of the requirement is for a page to consume whole browser window space but not overflow it. Overflow could, however, happen in separate sections (like in this case - sidebar).

So I've decided to use flexbox for layout, however can't figure out how to make sidebar scrollable if it's content is bigger than place given to it by the layout engine.

I've built an example to better explain my problem. When there is not too much content (content size is smaller than the container), everything looks as expected:

```css
html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .block {
        border: 1px solid grey;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .container > .header {
        flex: 0 1 auto;
        height: 65px;
    }

    .container > .content {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .container > .content > .page {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
    }

    .container > .content > .sidebar {
        flex: 0 1 auto;
        width: 250px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }

    .container > .footer {
        flex: 0 1 auto;
        height: 150px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="block header">
        <p>
        <b>Header</b>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="block sidebar">
            <p>
          <b>Sidebar</b>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="block page">
            <p>
          <b>Content</b>
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block footer">
        <p>
        <b>Footer</b>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

But if, for example, sidebar's content size is bigger than the sidebar itself, the footer gets pushed down and it causes the whole page to overflow the browser window size:

```css
html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .block {
        border: 1px solid grey;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .container > .header {
        flex: 0 1 auto;
        height: 65px;
    }

    .container > .content {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .container > .content > .page {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
    }

    .container > .content > .sidebar {
        flex: 0 1 auto;
        width: 250px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }

    .container > .footer {
        flex: 0 1 auto;
        height: 150px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="block header">
        <p>
        <b>Header</b>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="block sidebar">
            <p>
          <b>Sidebar</b>
            </p>
            <div style="background-color: blue; height: 800px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="block page">
            <p>
          <b>Content</b>
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block footer">
        <p>
        <b>Footer</b>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

How I could fix this problem and force sidebar to add scrolling behaviour when content doesn't fit the container rather than expand the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `overflow-y: auto;`, this will solve your problem.